# How to connect a pod in Kind with a local database

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kind

I am trying to connect a pod which is running in **Kind** with a local Postgres database which runs in a Docker container. I tried to add the following service but the pod still cannot connect when using the DNS name `postgres.dev.svc`.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres
  namespace: dev
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: 10.0.2.2
```

Is there another way to connect these two components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it's not the correct usage of the `ExternalName` service type. Although putting an IP address in `externalName` field it's perfectly feasible  i.e. the resource will be created and you won't get any complaint from kubernetes API server. ❗**But this value is treated as a domain name, comprised of digits, not as an IP adress**. You can read about it in [the official kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname):

> **Note:** ExternalName accepts an IPv4 address string, but as a DNS names comprised of digits, not as an IP address. ExternalNames that
> resemble IPv4 addresses are not resolved by CoreDNS or ingress-nginx
> because ExternalName is intended to specify a canonical DNS name. To
> hardcode an IP address, consider using [headless
> Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services).

So what you really need here is [Service without a selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors):

> Services most commonly abstract access to Kubernetes Pods, but they
> can also abstract other kinds of backends. For example:
>
> - You want to have an external database cluster in production, but in your test environment you use your own databases.
> - You want to point your Service to a Service in a different  [Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces)
>   or on another cluster.
> - You are migrating a workload to Kubernetes. While evaluating the approach, you run only a portion of your backends in Kubernetes.
>
> In any of these scenarios you can define a Service  *without*  a Pod
> selector. For example:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: my-service
> spec:
>   ports:
>     - protocol: TCP
>       port: 80
>       targetPort: 9376
> ```
>
> Because this Service has no selector, the corresponding Endpoints
> object is not created automatically. You can manually map the Service
> to the network address and port where it's running, by adding an
> Endpoints object manually:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Endpoints
> metadata:
>   name: my-service
> subsets:
>   - addresses:
>       - ip: 192.0.2.42
>     ports:
>       - port: 9376
> ```

In your particular case your `Service` definition may look as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```

and the corresponding `Endpoints` object may look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: postgres
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.0.2.2
    ports:
      - port: 5432
```

Of course the IP address `10.0.2.2` must be reachable from within your kubernetes cluster.

Comment: thx for sharing your insights, was def interesting!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One thing I also had to do is to add the container to the kind network (`docker network connect kind [CONTAINER_ID]`).

Comment: in my case `10.0.2.2` is not reachable, what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I can give some recommendation how i would try to debug such an issue.

1. Make sure you can log in to the database from your workstation or another host, so we can rule out that this problem is docker/database-host related.
2. Check if you can reach your database from your cluster or if traffic is blocked by for example a firewall. You can spawn a tmp container for this use case `kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh` and then try to ping, curl, wget ... the ip (busybox includes only wget, but feel free to use another image)
3. Hardcode the Ip in the Connection String instead of using an external Service for dns in your namespace.

If this does not solve the problem you might want to post a more detailed description.